# Position Lightbox - Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I need to position my lightbox over a part of the image. I tried adding this CSS:

```
#globe{
position:absolute;
left:170px;
top: 50px;
}
```

When I do that it breaks the lightbox. How do I position the lightbox? (I am using Fancybox) here is my HTML:

```
<p><a id="fancy" href="#globe"><img class="center" style="width:620px;" 
src="/messages4u/2011/images/october/baby-n-grandfather.jpg" /></a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="hide"><div id="globe">
<img src="/messages4u/2011/images/october/globe-text.png" width="400" 
height="400" /></div></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
$j("a#fancy").fancybox({
    'padding' : 0,
    'overlayShow' : false,
});
});
</script>
```

Now how do I position the image where I want it displayed in the lightbox?

Comment: You changed the entry, is it working now, does the fancybox show up? you just want to position it somewhere else then?

Comment: Yes the CSS caused it to break and not display. Fixed that so I reworded question to ask about my next issue which is how do I position the lightbox.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the fancy box effect only to the certain part of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target fancybox-outer

```
#fancybox-outer{
position:absolute;
left:170px;
top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It was actually #fancybox-wrap. I got it now =>

Comment: Also Lynda, you can re-write your jQuery code to this:jQuery(function() {
    $("a#fancy").fancybox({
        'padding': 0,
        'overlayShow': false
    });
});